# Why Does TowelRoot Require Internet / Network Access?

Tags: rooting, root-access, security

I read a blog post somewhere that suggested TowelRoot does not need internet access, and I've also read that it does. The latest version I tried to run TowelRoot v3 will not work without it. Is it downloading or sending any information? If so, what?

Addendum: I suppose if they were trying to accomplish anything nefarious, they would just do it instead of asking for permission... right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since TowelRoot's code is not publicly available, I resorted to decompile the latest APK, downloaded from the [TowelRoot website](http://towelroot.com), in order to investigate the app's need for the INTERNET permission.

---

### Relevant notes

Upon successful decompilation, it turned out that neither the activities nor the code itself be obfuscated. The developer certainly had anticipated that this app would've been investigated, yet he had left the code to be as much transparent as possible.
The most important file we have at this point is `TowelRoot.smali`, which describes all the workings of this app.

*Note: depending on your particular version of ApkTool, the line numbers may vary.*

---

### Initial structure

In lines `13-22`, the code initializes a field called `fingerprint`. The relevant code follows:

```
.field fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;
    .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
        value = {
            "Ljava/util/List",
            "<",
            "Lorg/apache/http/NameValuePair;",
            ">;"
        }
    .end annotation
.end field
```

which is a Java list composed of key-value pairs, to be used when collecting the relevant info from the phone.

---

### Data collected

In lines `56-215`, the code describes a method called `fillInFingerprint`, which is responsible for retrieving the appropriate data to be sent to the TowelRoot website, in order to ascertain whether the device can be rooted via the homonymous exploit. This method makes an extensive use of the abovementioned `fingerprint` field. The collected data follows.

#### Device model

The visible device model. Lines `70-80`:

```
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;

new-instance v5, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;

const-string v6, "model"

sget-object v7, Landroid/os/Build;->MODEL:Ljava/lang/String;

invoke-direct {v5, v6, v7}, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

invoke-interface {v4, v5}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

#### Device fingerprint

An unique identifier for the OS build. Lines `83-93`:

```
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;

new-instance v5, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;

const-string v6, "fingerprint"

sget-object v7, Landroid/os/Build;->FINGERPRINT:Ljava/lang/String;

invoke-direct {v5, v6, v7}, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

invoke-interface {v4, v5}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

#### Device hardware

Likely the processor board. Lines `96-106`:

```
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;

new-instance v5, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;

const-string v6, "hardware"

sget-object v7, Landroid/os/Build;->HARDWARE:Ljava/lang/String;

invoke-direct {v5, v6, v7}, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

invoke-interface {v4, v5}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

#### Device serial

Device's unique serial number. Lines `109-119`:

```
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;

new-instance v5, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;

const-string v6, "serial"

sget-object v7, Landroid/os/Build;->SERIAL:Ljava/lang/String;

invoke-direct {v5, v6, v7}, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

invoke-interface {v4, v5}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

#### Device kernel version

Vital since the exploit is likely to have been patched in the recent kernels. Lines `122-134`:

```
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;

new-instance v5, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;

const-string v6, "kernel"

invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->javaSucksAssReadTheKernelVersion()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v7

invoke-direct {v5, v6, v7}, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

invoke-interface {v4, v5}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

#### TowelRoot version

Lines `168-180`:

```
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;

new-instance v5, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;

const-string v6, "appversion"

invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->getSoftwareVersion()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v7

invoke-direct {v5, v6, v7}, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

invoke-interface {v4, v5}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

#### Modstring

The string `modstring`. Lines `202-211`:

```
.local v1, "modstring":Ljava/lang/String;
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;

new-instance v5, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;

const-string v6, "modstring"

invoke-direct {v5, v6, v1}, Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

invoke-interface {v4, v5}, Ljava/util/List;->add(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

---

### The server request

In lines `227-329` the code describes the method `queryServer`, which queries the server's database in order to find a match with the collected data, and handles the possible exceptions in the code. Such data is transmitted to the URL `https://towelroot.appspot.com/report/` via SSL and a POST request (lines `263-275`):

```
.local v2, "httppost":Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost;
new-instance v5, Lorg/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity;

iget-object v6, p0, Lcom/geohot/towelroot/TowelRoot;->fingerprint:Ljava/util/List;

invoke-direct {v5, v6}, Lorg/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity;-><init>(Ljava/util/List;)V

invoke-virtual {v2, v5}, Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost;->setEntity(Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntity;)V

.line 88
invoke-interface {v1, v2}, Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;->execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lorg/apache/http/HttpResponse;

move-result-object v3
```

---

### make it ra1n

The method `buttonClicked` (lines `333-426`) contains the code that makes the app work when you push the button. Amongst others, it calls the methods `fillInFingerprint` to gather the required info, and `queryServer` to see if the device can be rooted.

It then proceeds by analyzing the server's response. If said response is empty, TowelRoot prompts you about the necessity of an Internet connection (lines `369-378`):

```
invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

move-result v2

if-eqz v2, :cond_1

.line 115
const-string v2, "Please ensure you are connected to the internet"

invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Landroid/widget/TextView;->setText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
```

If the response is not empty, then TowelRoot proceeds by checking if the abovementioned equals the string `nyet` (lines `391-402`):

```
const-string v2, "nyet"

invoke-virtual {v0, v2}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

move-result v2

if-eqz v2, :cond_2

.line 117
const-string v2, "This phone isn\'t currently supported"

invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Landroid/widget/TextView;->setText(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
```

If the response equals `nyet`, then the phone isn't officially supported.

Finally, if the response is both non-empty and different from `nyet`, TowelRoot starts the rooting procedure by calling the native method `rootTheShit`, defined at line `448` and probably contained inside the library `libexploit.so`.

---

### For the brave ones

TowelRoot includes a special mode for users with unsupported devices. This mode, whose code is defined inside the method `titleClicked` (lines `451-504`), is accessible by tapping the red `welcome to towelroot v3` title inside the app, and will allow the user to try different modstrings in order to try to root the device anyway.